# In TextView, how do I change only part of the Text Style?

Tags: android

sorry, question's title was created in google translate.
My english is too short..

anyway, my question is How to change part of text style, in One TextView..

Example,

TextView1's text:

```
Hi, I am a Human. // Default TextSize 10
Hi, I am a Elf. // Change TextColor Blue
Hi, I am a Oak.  // Change TextColor Green, TextSize 15
Hi, I am a Dragon. // Change TextColor Red, TextSize 18
```

is that possible?

Comment: [http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring)

Comment: If you have written text of `textview` in `res/values/strings.xml` file then it is so easy to change the `text style` and `text color`. Just apply `html` tags to your text in `res/values/strings.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spannable string, or some library with rich textview widget, such as https://github.com/quiqueqs/BabushkaText

Comment: Voted for this! BabushkaText is a great library and really makes your life easier if you have to do lots of styles in TextViews.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem i use calligraphy

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

It working fine....